# How to stop DOM searching loop while the first match is found?

Tags: javascript, dom, loops, replace, nodes

I've modify a dom search/replace script, to replace multiple keywords matching on it, by a link, in a document.

It was working great without any `<div>` or `<p>`, but with a complex structure the keywords of each node are replaced...

This an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FRyjK/1/)

As you could see, the same keyword is not linked several times in an element, but while there is some other elements the keywords are linked...

This is the script

```
(function(){
    // don't replace text within these tags
    var skipTags = { 'a': 1, 'style': 1, 'script': 1, 'iframe': 1, 'meta':1, 'title':1, 'img':1, 'h1':1 };
    // find text nodes to apply replFn to
    function findKW( el, term, replFn ) 
    {
        var child, tag;
        if(!found)var found=false;
        for (var i = 0;i<=el.childNodes.length - 1 && !found; i++)
        {
            child = el.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType == 1) 
            { // ELEMENT_NODE
                tag = child.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                if (!(tag in skipTags)) 
                {
                    findKW(child, term, replFn);
                }
            } 
            else if (child.nodeType == 3) 
            { // TEXT_NODE
                found=replaceKW(child, term, replFn);
            }
        }
     };    
    // replace terms in text according to replFn
    function replaceKW( text, term, replFn) 
    {
        var match,
            matches = [],found=false;
        while (match = term.exec(text.data)) 
        {
            matches.push(match);
        }
        for (var i = 0;i<=matches.length - 1 && !found; i++)
        {           
            match = matches[i];            
            // cut out the text node to replace
            text.splitText(match.index);
            text.nextSibling.splitText(match[1].length);
            text.parentNode.replaceChild(replFn(match[1]), text.nextSibling);
            if(matches[i])found=true;// To stop the loop            
        }
        return found;
    };
    // Keywords to replace by a link
    var terms=Array('keywords','words');
    for(kw in terms)
    {
        findKW(
            document.body, 
            new RegExp('\\b(' + terms[kw] + ')\\b', 'gi'),
            function (match) 
            {
              var link = document.createElement('a');
              link.href = 'http://www.okisurf.com/#q=' + terms[kw];
              link.id = '1';
              link.target = '_blank';
              link.innerHTML = match;
              return link;
            }
        );
    }
}());​
```

**Please anyone could help me to stop the loop and replace only the first keyword matching ?** (I'm going crazy with those nodes and the `var found` that I can't send like global while the threads are working in loop, for the `findKW()` function...) And without any library (no jQuery or other)

Comment: like the answer: use a return on the find position or, if you want to go ahead in the function, use break to stop the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `true` when you replaced the the word, and test for it to stop the recursion:

```
if (child.nodeType == 1) { // ELEMENT_NODE
    tag = child.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (!(tag in skipTags)) {
        // If `findKW` returns `true`, a replacement as taken place further down
        // the hierarchy and we can stop iterating over the other nodes.
        if (findKW(child, term, replFn)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
} else if (child.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE
    if (replaceKW(child, term, replFn)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And remove any reference to `found` in this function, it is not needed.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FRyjK/2/) *(I also updated the `replaceKW` function, you don't need to collect all matches if you are only using the first one anyway)*.

Answer (score 0):

Use break statement to exist from a loop block.

**Example :**

```
for(;;) {
   if(condition) 
     break;
}
```

In your case you should add this on following position

```
else if (child.nodeType == 3) 
{ // TEXT_NODE
     found=replaceKW(child, term, replFn);
     if(found)
       break; // or alternately use return;
}
```

Comment: This does not suffice since he is using recursion.

Comment: @FelixKling, i am just giving him a approach to stop the execution.

Comment: Ok, all I'm saying that this is not enough to achieve what the OP wants: http://jsfiddle.net/FRyjK/3/.

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan I've already breaked everywhere with no success... I'm not noob like that lol